# Improve these opencv nested loop

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to check each pixcel in 11 imgs,get rid of the extremum,and use the center value to calculate mean value.

```py
    import cv2  
    import numpy as np

    img1 = cv2.imread("J:/1.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img2 = cv2.imread("J:/2.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img3 = cv2.imread("J:/3.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img4 = cv2.imread("J:/4.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img5 = cv2.imread("J:/5.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img6 = cv2.imread("J:/6.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img7 = cv2.imread("J:/7.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img8 = cv2.imread("J:/8.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img9 = cv2.imread("J:/9.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img10 = cv2.imread("J:/10.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img11 = cv2.imread("J:/11.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    imgList = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9, img10, img11]  

    height = img1.shape[0]
    width = img1.shape[1]
    imgall = np.array(imgList)

    png = np.zeros((height, width, 4), dtype=np.uint8)

    start1 = cv2.getTickCount()
    for yh in range(height):
        for xw in range(width):
            pstd = np.std(imgall[:, yh, xw, :], axis=0)
            pstdmean = np.mean(pstd)
            if pstdmean < 50:
                if pstdmean < 10:
                    png[yh, xw] = list(np.mean(imgall[:, yh, xw, :], axis=0)) + [255]
                else:
                    pmedian = np.median(imgall[:, yh, xw, :], axis=0)
                    png[yh, xw] = list(pmedian) + [255]
    end1 = cv2.getTickCount()
    during1 = (end1 - start1) / cv2.getTickFrequency()
    print(during1)
```

I'm trying to find how to get "gather number"/"mode number",like:histogram,Euclidean Distance,bgr2grey,Normal distribution...

I would like to replace this poor median method.

Answer (score 0):

no one answer me.but lucklly,I found the answer by myself.
It must be truned to numpy calculation and the for nested loop is shoulddnt be used.
I split bgr to b[] g[] r[],so they could calculate one by one,and ease to be understand.
then I stack(axis=-1) these 11 imgs to each channel ,it's easy to be understand and be calculated,finnaly I stack b g r to one img,and use mask = cv2.inRange(xxx, a, b) help me get what I want.png's alpha channel is use mask too.
png=np.stack((b, g, r, mask), axis=-1)